# Codeigniter :adding values to array using get_where

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

i am getting values from datbase using get_where clause for my login like this

**Controller:**

```
public function  submit_login(){
            if($this->input->post('submit')){
                $email= $this->input->post('email');
                $password= $this->input->post('password');
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $result= $this->user_model->login($email, $password);

              print_r($result);
            }
        }
```

**Model**

```
public function login($email, $password){
        $query=$this->db->get_where('user',array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password));
             if($query->num_rows()>0){
                return $query->result();
            }
        return false ; 
    }
```

it returns followint array

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [name] => Sikander [email]
>   => sikander@test.com [password] => password [mobile_number] => 1234 [role] => seller [points] => 0 ) )

Now i tried to loop this and assign id to sesion but foreach does not seem to work with this , dont know why pleas help

Answer (score 2):

Application should work in matter model returns only one result. 
Which you have there. As you see you got an array with one element `[0]` that is an object. Following OOP approach you can reach those properties (values) by:

```
$result[0]->id;
```

Alternatively, as one row from database is expected, in model you can return:

```
return $query->row();
```

and check it by

```
$result->id
```

If array syntax is more convinient for you to iterate, you can use

```
$query->result_array()
```

or

```
$query->row_array()
```

methods. There is plenty of useful examples in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public function login($email, $password){
    $query=$this->db->get_where('user',array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password));
         if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
        }
    return false ; 
}
```

IN your code return $query->result(); give array with object so in

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
                  echo $user->email; // what ever your table fields          

                        }
```

If you want only single value form the query so you need to 
return $query->result(); replace with

```
return $query->row(); // this return as object  or 
return $query->row_array();// this return as single array
```